# Firestore data won't load until I change code file on React Native App

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

This might sound weird but my Firestore data won't display on my app unless I save my code files.

Here is my screen when I get to the screen for the first time. Also, the items under Today's Deals are hard-coded.

[image]

Then here is my screen when I save my merchant.js file in vscode.

[image]

```
const store = route.params;

    const [items, setItems]=useState([])
    let storeItems;
    const getStoreItems = async()=>{
        let merchantId_str = String(store.merchantId);
        const response = firestore().collection('Items').where('merchantId', '==', merchantId_str)
        const data = await response.get();
        
        data.docs.forEach(item=>{
            items.push(item.data());
        })
    }

      storeItems = getUniqueListBy(items, 'sukiId');
      storeCategs = getUniqueListByCateg(items, 'storeCateg');
      
      
    useEffect(() => {
        getStoreItems();
    }, [])
```

I've tried to console.log(Items) as well when nothing loads and it's empty.

Comment: The error seems to lie in the code itself. Could you explain what you are trying to do with the route.params line?

Comment: That part works fine as it is just taking the data that I passed from the previous page. I think it's something to do with my useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to modify the read-only state of  items at

```
items.push(item.data());
```

Use the provided setItems function instead. Something like this should work:

```
let receivedData = [];

data.docs.forEach(item=>{
    receivedData.push(item.data());
})

setItems(receivedData);
```

You should be receiving some sort of a warning message in the console though about this.

Comment: Even though I've found this not to be the problem. This does make more sense for retrieving data.

Comment: That's interesting, I have a project on firestore now and when I replicated your situation on it, it acted identically. After making the fix it was fine.

It might not appear as a problem if you have some other component causing an update to some state that makes the app re-render. In that case the mistake would be hidden because of the other component (or save) that's initiating the re-render.

Comment: Thank you. This has actually solved the issue. Not sure what I was doing before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your usecase is not suitable for "useEffect" hook.

> What does useEffect do? By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render.

You may explore on "useState".

> useState is a Hook that lets you add React state to function components.

Read more about [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) on the official React docs.

Comment: I'm trying to call a function to get data from firestore and places it in an object. The problem is that the function won't fire at all even without the UseEffect.